# Spark AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'weekofyear'

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I need get the week number of the year

```
      from pyspark.sql.functions import weekofyear
      dt =sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08',)], ['a'])
      dt = dt.weekofyear(dt.a).alias('week')
      dt.show()
```

But I got this error:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'weekofyear'

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine.

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import weekofyear
 dt =sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08',)], ['a'])
 dt = dt.select('*',weekofyear(dt.a).alias('week'))
 dt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be:

```
weekofyear(dt.a).alias('week')
```

instead of:

```
dt.weekofyear(dt.a).alias('week')
```

as `weekofyear()` is a SQL function - it's not a DataFrame method...

Comment: Thanks for your reminding.I made the changes and it works as following